# how to fetch value of gwt combobox using selenium web driver?

Tags: gwt, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to test  GWT web application using selenium webdriver. I want to fetch the value of selected option of the combobox of gwt.  Can please someone tell me how can i do that.
Thanks

Comment: Please share your code as well what have you tried??..

Comment: What do you mean by value..Option's value or visible option's text??..

Answer (score 0):

You can view value selected, as given below -

```
Select combo1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of combobox")));
WebElement comboOptionSelected = combo1.getFirstSelectedOption();
System.out.println("Selected option is " + comboOptionSelected.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the selected option from the combo box follow the below one.

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dropDownElementID")));       
WebElement option = dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption();
option.getText();
```

If you want to select a value use the below one.

```
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("text");
```

Try the code and let me know the result.